# Unable to Parse JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: android, json, android-volley

> This is my JSON (full JSON is here : https://pastebin.com/kyPMWcTT):

```
 "replies": [
        [
           {
              "id": 2,
              "parent": 0,
              "author": 1,
              "author_name": "admin",
              "author_url": "http://localhost/wordpress",
              "date": "2021-05-02T08:38:00",
              "content": {
                 "rendered": "<p>Nice Blog, Awesome !</p>\n"
              },
              "link": "http://localhost/wordpress/2021/05/01/one-pot-thai-style-rice-noodles/#comment-2",
              "type": "comment",
             
              }
        ]
```

> I am trying to get the `rendered` item which is inside the `content` Object .
> This is the Code i have tried :

```
   JSONArray replyArray = embeddedObject.getJSONArray("replies");
                            for (int j = 0; j < replyArray.length(); j++) {
                                JSONObject contentObject = replyArray.getJSONObject(j);
                                JSONObject getContent = contentObject.getJSONObject("content");
                                String reply = getContent.getString("rendered");
                                Log.e("Reply is", reply);
                            }
```

> But, the Logcat output is :

```
Value at 0 of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

> How to solve this problem ? What am i doing wrong ? Please Guide

Comment: Your JSON has a nested array for some reason? It goes `replies -> array -> array ` if you have a look at it properly.

Comment: @HenryTwist So, how do I parse this nested Array ? It has no name at all

Comment: You can use `JSONArray.getJSONArray` to obtain items in an array, which you're already using in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What's Happening?**

We are trying to fetch the JSONObject immediately after `replies` JSONArray. But, the actual `content` lies in the following hierarchy.

```
replies JSONObject -> JSONArray -> JSONArray -> ContentObject -> Content
```

**Solution**

**Replace this**

```
JSONArray replyArray = embeddedObject.getJSONArray("replies");
for (int j = 0; j < replyArray.length(); j++) {
      JSONObject contentObject = replyArray.getJSONObject(j);
      JSONObject getContent = contentObject.getJSONObject("content");
      String reply = getContent.getString("rendered");
      Log.e("Reply is", reply);
}
```

**With this**

```
JSONArray replyArray = embeddedObject.getJSONArray("replies");
for (int j = 0; j < replyArray.length(); j++) {
      JSONArray replySubArray = replyArray.getJSONArray(j);
      for (int i = 0; i < replySubArray.length(); j++) {
            JSONObject contentObject = replySubArray.getJSONObject(i);
            JSONObject getContent = contentObject.getJSONObject("content");
            String reply = getContent.getString("rendered");
            Log.e("Reply is", reply);
      }
}
```

Comment: Thanks So much Buddy !